# Create a SaveTo-Dialog in flexdashboard with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, flexdashboard

I'm quite lost... I'd like to add a save-button to my shiny/flexdashboard-app. First I tried to use 'shiny files' but it seems that this doesn't work with rmarkdown somehow.
Is there another possibility to create a decent "save-to"-Dialog (like a dialog opens up, one can choose the path and set a filename, hits OK and the file gets saved (the saving-part is no problem))?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `downloadButton()` (or `downloadLink()`) and `downloadHandler()` should also work in flexdashboard. You can find the documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/downloadButton.html).